# Get dropdown / checkbox / multiselect field values on frontend submit

Tags: field, entry

I would like to allow registered users to submit entries to sections. The documentation didn't mention how to get the values and labels of dropdown / checkbox / multiselect fields to show them as options on the submitting page. I can't use the `entry` variable because the entry is not saved yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get info about your fields using [craft.fields.getFieldByHandle()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.fields#getFieldByHandle). That will include a `settings` property, which will be an array of the field type’s settings.

The actual settings available will differ depending on the field type, but Dropdown, Checkboxes, and Multi-select fields all have the same one: `options`. So in each of their cases, here’s how you would loop through the options:

```html
{% set field = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('myFieldHandle') %}
{% for opt in field.settings.options %}
    <label>
        <input name="fields[myFieldHandle][]" type="checkbox" value="{{ opt.value }}">
        {{ opt.label }}
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried to figure this out a while ago but couldn't. I don't think `field.settings` is mentioned anywhere [in the docs](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/FieldModel), unless I'm mistaken? It's quite handy when you want to grab generic field options rather than setting up `user` or `entry`.

Comment: Why do you have the `<input>`'s `name` parameter set to `fields[myFieldHandle][]` instead of just `myFieldHandle[]` - or even more automated, `field.handle[]`?

Comment: @Sandwich Because Craft expects all of the custom field POST values to be tucked away in a `fields` namespace.

Comment: Ok, so would the automated ideal be `fields[{{ field.handle }}][]`?

Comment: @Sandwich Yeah you could do `fields[{{ field.handle }}][]` if you want. Seems overkill in this example since `field` was literally fetched by its handle, so not much need to make it dynamic here.

Comment: True, but wouldn't it allow one to generate frontend form field code similarly to how Matrix frontend code works? Pseudocode: `if field.handle.type == 'dropdown' use this code, elseif field.handle.type == 'radio' use that code`?